# osgeo4w not installing processing tools in QGIS toobox.

Tags: qgis, saga, osgeo4w, toolbox

I have uninstalled and reinstalled QGIS several times from the OSGeo4W application.  I have done this with no problem on several other times, but now I cannot get the tools to load.  Most of the help simply say to just use the OSGeo4W application and not to worry about anything else.  What do you do when the OSGeo4W application is not working.

Do I need to change the Windows environment variables manually?  I have never had to do this before.

Comment: Is the Qgis prefix path supposed to have back or forward slashes?  Currently the "QGIS_PREFIX_PATH" is "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis"  while every other environment variable has backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

I now see you just have to switch option at the bottom of the toolbox from "simple" to "advanced".

https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/processing/toolbox.html?highlight=configuration%20dialog

[image]

I have never had to do this before.